# Eclipse - Reference file in another Project

Tags: java, eclipse, file, relative-path

**Edit:** My solution at bottom of post.

I have 2 projects that share the same XML/XSD data in eclipse.  I've tried many different things to break the data into a separate project and just reference that instead through various methods, with not much luck.  My goal is so I can click run in eclipse for each project separately and they both load from the same data.

When the project is finally built, there will be 3 jars (the two projects,+ a lib), which will be in the same directory with the xml and xsd folders.  So any file references to the XSD/XMLs are currently in the format like this:

```
File file = new File("xml/pixtilemaps.xml");
```

This doesn't work in eclipse, but works during export because of the file structure is sound.  I tried using virtual folders in each of the projects, but it doesn't look like runtime references to relative files use the virtual folders in the way I was expecting.  I've tried adding each as a linked resource, added the project on the build path, etc, but whatever I do, it doesn't seem to treat the xml folder as a relative folder.  I get an error like : file:/F:/workspace/com.myoid.editor/xsd/pixtilemaps.xsd does not exist.  Because it takes it relative to the project. I've also tried to find a run configuration solution to this, but there is obviously something I'm not understanding to get this to work the way I want.

So in summary, have an xsd folder, xml folder in a 3rd eclipse project, that I want 1 and 2 to be able to access through relative file paths like

```
File file = new File("xml/pixtilemaps.xml");
```

**How I fixed it:**

Okay.. so.. maybe there is a better solution but this is what I came up with... In Eclipse under run configurations you can specify the working directory that the launch will run from.  So I put all xml/xsd in for both projects in the same "working directory".  In the run configuration for each project I point the working directory to the 3rd project, and viola, it works like I had expected.

Answer (score 1):

Add third project n the build path of first two projects as `project reference`.

Use [**ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) in place of `File` in first two projects as below:

```
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xml/pixtilemaps.xml");
```

Comment: This almost works, but the problem is that the XSDs reference other XSDs that it can't find when I load the main XSD this way.  If I could just find a way to get eclipse to treat virtual folders/linked resource references as part of the project then I think it would work..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to reference project 3 in project 1 and 2 via project menu -> properties -> java build path -> add project?

Comment: Yep, but the reference to the file object is in project 1/2 using File file = new File("xml/pixtilemaps.xml");  But this file exists in project 3.  Adding the project in this way it still can't see the file.

Comment: You could try to access the workspace programmatically like they did in this thread: http://www.coderanch.com/t/453807/vc/find-Workspace-through-Java-code

Comment: This would inject eclipse dependencies into my code which is not what I want since the project is exported with as few of dependencies as possible.